# How to Populate a GridView with a DropDownList value

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have created a connection string, and i am populating a dropdownlist with an ID from a sql database.

I want to be able to click on a ID from the dropdownlist and run a query to populate a gridview with data. I have made the dropdownlist `autopostback = Enabled`. I am not getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlContracts.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim umsContractsContractID As String = "select * from umsContracts where ContractID=' " & ddlContracts.SelectedValue & " '"
    Dim umsContractBillContractID As String = "select * from umsContractBills where ContractID=' " & ddlContracts.SelectedValue & " '"

    Dim Contracts As New SqlDataAdapter(umsContractsContractID, connstring)
    Dim Bill As New SqlDataAdapter(umsContractBillContractID, connstring)

    Contracts.Fill(ds, "umsContracts")
    Bill.Fill(ds, "umsContractBill")

    gvContracts.DataSource = ds.Tables("umsContracts").DefaultView
    gvContracts.DataBind()
    gvContractBill.DataSource = ds.Tables("umsContractBill").DefaultView
    gvContractBill.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: "I am not getting an error". So what is your question, what does not work?

Answer (score 0):

where have you kept the dropdown binding function ? is your dropdownlist binding on every postback or you kept it inside !IsPostback clause ?

Answer (score 0):

try putting the property autopostback = true for your dropdownlist, if not set to true.